# Existence of a continuous function $ \theta $ with $ f ( x ) = | f ( x ) | \exp \big( i \theta ( x ) \big) $

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, continuity

> Consider a continuous function $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C \setminus \{ 0 \} $. Is there a continuous function $ \theta : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that $ f ( x ) = | f ( x ) | \exp \big( i \theta ( x ) \big) $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $?

### My thoughts:

I intuitively think that this is true. Suppose that we fix some value for $ \theta ( 0 ) = \arg f ( 0 ) $ from the infinite possibilities (which differ from the one we fixed by an integer multiple of $ 2 \pi $). As $ f $ only takes nonzero values and is continuous, for all $ x \in \mathbb R $ close enough to $ 0 $, the angle between the positive real axis and the line joining $ f ( x ) $ to the origin in the complex plane is as close as we want to the corresponding angle for $ f ( 0 ) $. From all the values we can take for the measure of this angle, there is only one that is that close to $ \theta ( 0 ) $, and choosing that one for $ \theta ( x ) $, $ \theta $ will be continuous around $ 0 $. This can intuitively be done over and over again for the new points other than $ 0 $ with a fixed value of $ \theta $, and thus the result we want.

I understand that there's a flaw with this reasoning, as for example after the first step, when we've found a neighborhood $ N $ of $ 0 $ with fixed value of $ \theta ( x ) $ for $ x \in N $, when we repeat the argument for a new point $ x _ 0 \in N $, the resulting neighborhood $ N _ 0 $ for $ x _ 0 $ may be completely included in $ N $, and we don't actually get any new points with fixed value of $ \theta $. This makes me think that if $ f $ is uniformly continuous or something, so that we can ensure $ N _ 0 $ is as large as $ N $, the above intuition can be made into a rigorous proof, but not necessarily for the case where the only condition on $ f $ is mere continuity.

In any case, I neither could find a counterexample nor could find a rigorous proof and go beyond the above intuition. So is the statement really true?

---

**P.S.** I'm aware of the fact that if the domain of $ f $ was say $ \mathbb C \setminus \{ 0 \} $, the statement didn't hold, as it is wrong even for a function as simple as the identity function. But it seems to be true for the case when the domain of $ f $ is $ \mathbb R $ or an interval. While my real question is the one above, I would really appreciate an answer which gives an insight about the kind of domains that make this statement true and the ones which make it false.

Comment: $\theta(x) = arg(f(0))+\Im(\int_0^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}dt)$. Equivalently split the real line in intervals where $arg(f(x))$ stays in $(-\pi,\pi)$ or $(0,2\pi)$, so you have a continuous arg on each interval, then add the needed $2k\pi$ to glue those local arg into a continuous function.

Comment: The result is true for any simply connected domain in the plane also - like in the case above, one always has a local version in the neighbourhood of any point. There is also path continuation that patches the local versions together on a path from a point to another; because of discreteness of the different local versions (they differ by $2k\pi$ in argument only), if you deform continuously a path to another, you keep same continuation, so the result follows; in the real case, whether line or interval, the patching can be done sequentially as noted in the comment above so result is simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposition:** For any $c\in\Bbb R$, the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\eta\colon&(c,c+2\pi)&\longrightarrow&S^1\\&t&\mapsto&e^{it}\end{array}$$is a homeomorphism onto $S^1\setminus\{e^{ic}\}$.

**Proof:** It is clear that $\eta\bigl((c,c+2\pi)\bigr)=S^1\setminus\{e^{ic}\}$ and that $\eta$ is continuous and injective. What remains to be proved is that $\eta^{-1}\colon S^1\setminus\{e^{ic}\}\longrightarrow(c,c+\pi)$ is continuous. Let $F\subset(c,c+\pi)$ be a closed subset. Then the inverse image of $F$ with respect to $\eta^{-1}$ is $\eta(F)$. Since $F$ is a closed subset of $(c,c+\pi)$, $F\cup\{c,c+2\pi\}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$. Actually, it is compact, since it is bounded too. But then $\{e^{iz}\mid z\in F\cup\{c,c+2\pi\}\}$ is a compact subset of $S^1$, and, in particular, it is a closed set. And$$\eta(F)=\{e^{iz}\mid z\in F\cup\{c,c+2\pi\}\}\setminus\{e^{ic}\},$$which is therefore a closed subset of $S^1\setminus\{e^{ic}\}$. Since the inverse image with respect to $\eta^{-1}$ of any closed subset of $(c,c+\pi)$ is a closed subset of $S^1\setminus\{e^{ic}\}$, $\eta^{-1}$ is continuous.

---

**Proposition:** If $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is a continuous map, then there is a continuous map $\theta\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that$$(\forall t\in\Bbb R):f(t)=|f(t)|e^{i\theta(t)}.$$

**Proof:** Let $F(t)=\frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}$; we want to prove that there is a continuous map $\theta\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that$$(\forall t\in\Bbb R):F(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}.$$Note that $F$ is a map from $\Bbb R$ into $S^1$. If $x\in\Bbb R$, then, since $F$ is continuous, there is some $\varepsilon_x>0$ such that $|y-x|<\varepsilon_x\implies|F(y)-F(x)|<2$. In particular, $F\bigl((x-\varepsilon_x,x+\varepsilon_x)\bigr)$ is not the whole $S^1$, since $-F(x)$ does not belong to it (because $F(x)\in S^1$ and therefore the distance from $F(x)$ to $-F(x)$ is equal to $2$). If $c\in\Bbb R$ is such that $e^{ic}=-F(x)$, then, by the previous proposition, the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\eta\colon&(x-\pi,x+\pi)&\longrightarrow&S^1\\&t&\mapsto&e^{it}\end{array}$$is a homeomorphism onto $S^1\setminus\{-F(x)\}$. If $\mu$ is its inverse, then$$(\forall t\in(x-\varepsilon_x,x+\varepsilon_x)):F(t)=\eta\bigl(\mu\bigl(F(t)\bigr)\bigr)=e^{i\mu(F(t))}.$$In particular,$$(\forall t\in(-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)):F(t)=e^{i\mu(F(t))}.$$So, if you define $T$ as the set of those $r\in(0,\infty)$ such that, for some continuous function $\theta\colon[0,r]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$, you have$$(\forall t\in[0,r]):F(t)=e^{i\theta(t)},$$then $T\ne\emptyset$, since it contains the interval $(0,\varepsilon_0)$. If $T\ne(0,\infty)$, then it has an upper bound. Let $s=\sup S$. We have seen that there is some interval $(s-\varepsilon_s,s+\varepsilon_s)$ and some continuous function $\theta\colon(s-\varepsilon_s,s+\varepsilon_s)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that we have $F(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}$ on $(s-\varepsilon_s,s+\varepsilon_s)$. Fix some $u\in T\cap(s-\varepsilon_s,s)$. Then, by the definition of $T$, there is some continuous function $\theta^\ast\colon[0,u]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that$$(\forall t\in[0,u]):F(t)=e^{i\theta^\ast(t)}.$$Since, on $[u,s)$ we have $e^{i\theta(t)}=e^{i\theta^\ast(t)}$, since both $\theta$ and $\theta^\ast$ are continuous, and since $[u,s)$ is an interval, there is some $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $(\forall t\in[u,s)):\theta(t)=\theta^\ast(t)+2n\pi$. So, if you replace $\theta^\ast$ by $\theta$ you will have$$(\forall t\in[0,s+\varepsilon_s)):F(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}.$$But then $T\supset[0,s+\varepsilon_s)$, which is impossible, since $s=\sup T$. We have reached a contradiction. So, the assumption that $T\ne(0,\infty)$ is false. In other words, there is a continuous function $\theta\colon[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that$$(\forall t\in[0,\infty)):F(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}$$and, by a similar argument, there is a continuous function $\theta\colon(-\infty,0]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that$$(\forall t\in(-\infty,0]):F(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}.$$